# Precomputed Web Audio API Time Domain and spectrogram Visualization

Tags: javascript, audio, visualization, web-audio-api

I'm synthesizing sound through the web audio api using various oscillators/filters and have time domain and spectrogram visualizations that run in real time as the oscillators play (similar to [here](http://apprentice.craic.com/tutorials/32) and [here](http://apprentice.craic.com/tutorials/33)).

However, I'm wanting to be able to create an initial precomputed visualization based on the audio network before its run for a set amount of time so a user can view what the network will sound like before playing it. Is this possible or is there a way to speed up time to quickly generate the visualizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an OfflineAudioContext, this gives you a PCM buffer back, asynchronously. Compute windowed RMS values out of that (or just use the time domain, depends on what you want to do), and put it on a  or whatever.

The OfflineAudioContext lets you run a graph as fast as the machine runs, and is a drop-in replacement for the AudioContext, apart from three nodes, that can't be used (MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode, MediaStreamSourceNode, and MediaElementAudioSourceNode), because MediaStream are real-time objects: they make no sense when not rendering in real-time.

It goes like this:

```
   var off = new OfflineAudioContext(2 /* stereo */,
                                     44100 /* length in frames */,
                                     44100 /* samplerate */);
   /* do your thing: setup your graph as usual */
   off.createOscillator(...);
   ...
   ...

   /* This is called when the graph has rendered one
    * second of audio, here: 44100 frames at 44100 frames per second */

   off.oncomplete = function(e) {
     e.renderedBuffer; /* is an AudioBuffer that contains the PCM data */
   };
   /* kick off the rendering */
   off.startRendering();
```

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need, must have missed that when reading the spec. Thanks!